# Android same screen resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution

In Android, I need same resolution for `Default(WVGA800)`
`HVGA` `QVGA` and all emulator that mean emulator's size should not matter right now I've this `xml file` and I'll need fix size for the bottom tab bar for that also what should I do? right now I am facing problem is.. I've to put space for tabbar at the bottom. so, when I'am run this same application in the Default(WVGA800) HVGA or QVGA it overlaps the webview on the tab bar so, it looks bad what should I do? I am using Android 1.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_height="371dip">
    <!--    <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewHelp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />-->
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewHelp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="8px" android:text="Download this mp3 file"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="33dip"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="this is button !"
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my tabbar activity class

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getTabHost();
        try {

            //GlobalVariable.Setdownload(0);
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(myclsname.class, "Welcome",
                    "Welcome", R.drawable.tab_icon_events));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(anotheclsname.class, ".Mp3List", ".Mp3List",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_pitchforkfm));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(AboutUs.class, "AboutUs", "AboutUs",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_home));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(ExtraInfromation.class, "ExtraInformation", "ExtraInformation",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_tv));

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height=57;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    bla.. bla.. bla..

    private TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag,
            final String title, final int drawable) 
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, intentClass);

        final View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        ((TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_text)).setText(title);
        ((ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon))
                .setImageResource(drawable);

        return getTabHost().newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tab)
                .setContent(intent);
    }
```

what should I do so, above problem will be solve?

Comment: Same resolution on screens that have different resolutions? If it's even possible, it will look really bad (like running iphone apps on an ipad in 2x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- **You can't get the same layout to work in all the different screens**. This has been repeated over and over here, and in the [android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). As explained in that link, you'll have to set up layout folders for each screen resolution group and create layouts for each one of them with the required sizes (at least `res/layout-small`, `res/layout-normal` and `res/layout-large`). Also, you will probably need to create a set of bitmaps (if you have any) for each screen density (`res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi` and `res/drawable-ldpi` at least).
- If you want to fix the tab at the bottom, follow the answers to this question: [How to reduce the tab bar height and display in bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683363/how-to-reduce-the-tab-bar-height-and-display-in-bottom).
- If you use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of a `LinearLayout`, then you can use `android:layout_above="@id/tabs"` to force android to render everything **above** the tabs and **not overlapping** them.
- If the content is bigger than the screen, then consider including your layout inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).
- Not relevant to this question, but very relevant for future questions in SO: please, try to avoid posting irrelevant code. The Java part has no interest in your question.

Comment: okk you mean to say i've to create main.xml file for each resoltion?

Comment: but then how can it provide setcontentview? i mean how can i determine which main.xml file i've to load?

Comment: It will be determined automatically at runtime depending on the screen of the device. Please, **read the links I posted**. I will repeat it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html in case you missed it.

Comment: Hi @Aleadam, if the Java part is irrelevant to the question, I would invite you to edit it out from the question. (I won't do it myself as I don't know enough about Android)