# setContentView for multiple resolutions

Tags: android, screen

From this  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313988/android-resolution-need-help/6314520#6314520) i knew that if i want to create android resolution for all the device then i've to use [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but how i can setcontentview for that?

Answer (score 0):

You give equivalent layouts the same file name within each resolution folder. Hence they have the same ID. You pass that ID to `setContentView(int layoutResID)` and the Android system picks the right one for the device.

You don't *have* to use multiple layouts though. If you design your layout carefully, so that the views stretch or scroll in a sensible way, you may be able to use just the one.

Comment: butt.... how can i... ok let me... i've created say i.e test.xml file and that file will be into my layout-small and layout-large.. ok? then how can i? it doesn't shows me when i pressing layout.(dot) then how?

Comment: I think you may need a default version in the plain *layout* folder, so it has something to load for a size that you haven't specified. Otherwise you may have to have one for every supported size before an ID gets generated (guessing here -- I've only done this for *layout* vs. *layout-land*).

Comment: Also, if using Eclipse, you will need to "Refresh" the *res* folder if you created those folders & files outside Eclipse. The IDs will only be generated if Eclipse knows about the files.

Comment: Have a look at [this sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html). You can browse the *res* folder from the web page.

Comment: You are calling setContentView(R.layout.test), and it's not compiling?