# Reduce Tab height and align text on top?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

how can i Reduce Tab height and align text on top?

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MessagesTabs extends TabActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messages_tabs);

        //Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GetMessages.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("inbox").setIndicator("Inbox")
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GetConversations.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("conversation").setIndicator("Conversation")
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        /*
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);*/

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }


}
```

xmlfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TabWidget          
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try this for increasing the height of the tabs :

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).getLayoutParams().height =(int) height;
```

for text aligning  try this in your xml layout :

`android:gravity="top"` or `android:layout_gravity="top"`

Answer (score 1):

use this code. It may work for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height /= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom layout for your tab, inflate it and use [setIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29)